# Rxjs concat example

Tags: angular, rxjs

Been using rxjs for a while now, but don't understand some things, one of which is concat. Example from the [rxjs site](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/concat.html):

```
    const sourceOne = of(1, 2, 3);
    //emits 4,5,6
    const sourceTwo = of(4, 5, 6);
    //emit values from sourceOne, when complete, subscribe to sourceTwo
    const example = sourceOne.pipe(concat(sourceTwo));
```

but, in my angular project this gives me this error:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'Observable<number>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<number, {}>'.
      Type 'Observable<number>' provides no match for the signature '(source: Observable<number>): Observable<{}>'.
```

Not sure why, can anyone enlighten me? Thanks.

Comment: are you sure you use the very same code? can you provide a minimal verifiable example of the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're importing wrong `concat`. You want to use it as an operator so you have to import

```
import { concat } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

You're importing `concat` from `'rxjs'` which is an observable creation method, not an operator.

This will be renamed in later version of RxJS because it's too misleading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3927

Comment: Thank you! VS Code did the import for me. Who would think it's a good idea to name 2 different things the same in the first place.

Comment: Yeah, you're not the first one who had exactly the same problem and not the last one either. This will be fixed however https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3927

Answer (score 1):

The example works fine. I recreated it on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-6z6pjk?file=index.ts

Code:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, concat } from 'rxjs/operators';

const sourceOne = of(1, 2, 3);
//emits 4,5,6
const sourceTwo = of(4, 5, 6);

//emit values from sourceOne, when complete, subscribe to sourceTwo
const example = sourceOne.pipe(
  concat(sourceTwo))
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "typescript-5i4anz",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "rxjs": "6.4.*"
  }
}
```